# Como recorrer array y guardarlos según datos en el objeto

Tags: javascript, typescript

yo tengo el siguiente array

```
[id, nombre, comida1, comida2, comida3],
[id, nombre, comida1, comida2, ''],
[id, nombre, comida1, '']
```

Yo recorro el array, con un "while", pero yo quiero guardar un registro de cada comida por usuario. No todos los usuarios van a tener las 3 comidas ejemplo:

```
1 | Saul | Arroz con pollo
2 | Saul | Tortillas azadas
3 | Saul | Pollo guisado

My codigo 

ConditionData(lines, values: Array<any>){
    while (lines !== null) {
        const info: FoodDto = {food: '', name: '', id:0}
        if (values.length >= 4 && values[4] !== '' && values[4] !== null) {
            console.log("entre aqui1", values[3])
            const id = parseInt(service + "1");
            info.name = values[1]
            info.food = values[2]
            info.id = id

            return info
        }
```

O sea en el recorrido dependiendo de las posiciones 2, 3 y 4 sean registros distintos por separados, pero con el mismo user de la posicion 2.
Asi como lo engo solo me trae el registro de comida 2 por cada usuario.

agradecido con sus comentarios

Answer (score 1):

```js
function procesar(arreglo){
  let contador = 1;
  let resultado = [];
  
  // recorrer todas las comidas empezando en la posición 2
  for(i = 2 ; i < arreglo.length; i++){
    if(arreglo[i].length > 0){
      // si hay un valor en la posición i agregarlo al arreglo
      // de resultados
      resultado.push(
       [
       contador++, // el número de la comida
       arreglo[1], // el nombre
       arreglo[i]  // nombre de la comida
      ]);
    }
  }
  
  return resultado;
}

console.log(procesar([1,'carlos','pollo','']));
console.log(procesar([1,'juan','pollo','carne','papas']));
```